# ejabberd - mucsub with ejabberdctl

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I try to get familiar with the new ejabberd feature (i.e. Multi-User Chat Subscriptions) and just wondering if there is any command that can get those useful info of the subscrition sub as per following

> List of subscriptions
>     - list of muc room subscribed for a particular user
>
> List of subscriber
>       - list of subscriber for a particular muc room

Note : `List of subscriptions` is technically can be retrieved via stanza. But I'm not able to find any document to use stanza for `List of subscriber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to retrieve the list of subscriptions for a user is described in the documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/#list-of-subscriptions

Getting the list of subscribers on a MUC room features is not yet implemented.

Comment: Thanks Mickaël for the clarification. For the list of subscription, is that possible to execute via ejabberdctl or mod_http_api as an admin on behalf of the user?